# Project is littered with random errors

Tags: java, android

As the title reads. These aren't the errors from R.java being deleted - It's still there in one piece. But for a few hundred lines of code in the middle of my project, there are random errors, which show no consistency. For example, there's a `Syntax error on token "case", assert expected` error on one case in the switch-case, but all the others are fine, `rnd1`, a local random variable, is supposedly a duplicate, but it's not. I've restarted Eclipse and cleaned the project countless times. Anyone know how to get rid of the errors?

Code which errors:

```
public void attack1Method() {
    switch (rand1) {
    case 1:
        if (minion1Hp > 0) {
            minion1Hp--;
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                        public void run() {
                            attack1.startAnimation(m1attack1);

                        }
                    }, 472);
                }

            });
            minion1Bar();
        }
        if (minion1Hp <= 0) {
            Random rnd1 = new Random();
            if (waveNum == 3 || waveNum == 6 || waveNum == 9) {
                rand1 = cannonNum[rnd1.nextInt(cannonNum.length)];
            } else {
                rand1 = minionNum[rnd1.nextInt(minionNum.length)];
            }
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    switch (rand6) {
                    case 1:
                        attack1.startAnimation(m1attack1);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        attack1.startAnimation(m1attack2);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        attack1.startAnimation(m1attack3);
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        attack1.startAnimation(m1attack4);
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        attack1.startAnimation(m1attack5);
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        attack1.startAnimation(m1attack6);
                        break;
                    case 7:
                        attack1.startAnimation(m1attack7);
                        break;
                    }
                }

            });
            }
        }
        break;
    case 2:
        if (minion2Hp > 0) {
            minion2Hp--;
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                        public void run() {
                            attack1.startAnimation(m1attack2);

                        }
                    }, 728);
                }

            });
            minion2Bar();
        }
        if (minion2Hp <= 0) {
            Random rnd1 = new Random();
            if (waveNum == 3 || waveNum == 6 || waveNum == 9) {
                rand1 = cannonNum[rnd1.nextInt(cannonNum.length)];
            } else {
                rand1 = minionNum[rnd1.nextInt(minionNum.length)];
            }
        }
        break;
    case 3:
        if (minion3Hp > 0) {
            minion3Hp--;
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                        public void run() {
                            attack1.startAnimation(m1attack3);

                        }
                    }, 900);
                }

            });
            minion3Bar();
        }
        if (minion3Hp <= 0) {
            Random rnd1 = new Random();
            if (waveNum == 3 || waveNum == 6 || waveNum == 9) {
                rand1 = cannonNum[rnd1.nextInt(cannonNum.length)];
            } else {
                rand1 = minionNum[rnd1.nextInt(minionNum.length)];
            }
        }
        break;
    case 4:
        if (minion4Hp > 0) {
            minion4Hp--;
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                        public void run() {
                            attack1.startAnimation(m1attack4);

                        }
                    }, 288);
                }

            });
            minion4Bar();
        }
        if (minion4Hp <= 0) {
            Random rnd1 = new Random();
            if (waveNum == 3 || waveNum == 6 || waveNum == 9) {
                rand1 = cannonNum[rnd1.nextInt(cannonNum.length)];
            } else {
                rand1 = minionNum[rnd1.nextInt(minionNum.length)];
            }
        }
        break;
    case 5:
        if (minion5Hp > 0) {
            minion5Hp--;
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                        public void run() {
                            attack1.startAnimation(m1attack5);

                        }
                    }, 500);
                }

            });
            minion5Bar();
        }
        if (minion5Hp <= 0) {
            Random rnd1 = new Random();
            if (waveNum == 3 || waveNum == 6 || waveNum == 9) {
                rand1 = cannonNum[rnd1.nextInt(cannonNum.length)];
            } else {
                rand1 = minionNum[rnd1.nextInt(minionNum.length)];
            }
        }
        break;
    case 6:
        if (minion6Hp > 0) {
            minion6Hp--;
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                        public void run() {
                            attack1.startAnimation(m1attack6);

                        }
                    }, 628);
                }

            });
            minion6Bar();
        }
        if (minion6Hp <= 0) {
            Random rnd1 = new Random();
            if (waveNum == 3 || waveNum == 6 || waveNum == 9) {
                rand1 = cannonNum[rnd1.nextInt(cannonNum.length)];
            } else {
                rand1 = minionNum[rnd1.nextInt(minionNum.length)];
            }
        }
        break;
    case 7:
        if (minion7Hp > 0) {
            minion7Hp--;
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                        public void run() {
                            attack1.startAnimation(m1attack7);

                        }
                    }, 868);
                }

            });
            minion7Bar();
        }
        if (minion7Hp <= 0) {
            Random rnd1 = new Random();
            if (waveNum == 3 || waveNum == 6 || waveNum == 9) {
                rand1 = cannonNum[rnd1.nextInt(cannonNum.length)];
            } else {
                rand1 = minionNum[rnd1.nextInt(minionNum.length)];
            }
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    switch (rand6) {
                    case 1:
                        attack1.startAnimation(m1attack1);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        attack1.startAnimation(m1attack2);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        attack1.startAnimation(m1attack3);
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        attack1.startAnimation(m1attack4);
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        attack1.startAnimation(m1attack5);
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        attack1.startAnimation(m1attack6);
                        break;
                    case 7:
                        attack1.startAnimation(m1attack7);
                        break;
                    }
                }

            });
            }
        }
        break;

    }
    if (attack1Stop == 0 && appRunning == 1) {
        attack1Thread.postDelayed(attack1Runnable, 1500);
    }
}
```

It gives me errors such as `Duplicate local variable rnd1` and `Duplicate local variable rnd1`. The code was working fine before, but now errors all over the method. There's even a few `Syntax error on token "}", delete this token` errors which occur occasionally.

All help appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried checking the specified lines for syntax errors? Missing semicolons, or missing or extra parentheses or braces are frequent unnoticed causes of weird syntax errors.

Comment: There's at least an extra `}` before the top-level `case 2`. Other "random" errors are probably due to similar errors.

Answer (score 0):

Could you post examples of some of the errors? I can't help you that much if I don't know where the errors occur.

As for the *"Syntax error on token "case", assert expected"* error, Eclipse will sometimes show this error when you have missed an open bracket, close bracket, or semicolon somewhere. Try looking through the case before the problematic one to find any missing characters.

If you haven't tried it yet, search through your file for "rnd1" to see if it is declared anywhere else.